# How does Ingress communicate with HTTPS backend?

Tags: ingress-controller, ingress-nginx

I am trying to understand how ssl termination works in ingress controller.

I have an HTTPS application running in K8S and behind ingress controller.

Does ingress controller decrypt the HTTPS traffic from client and encrypt it again with its configured tls secret before sending to the backend ?

If yes, do we say ingress controller applies "ssl termination" or "ssl passthrough" ?